# Creating Soft Links

Tags: file, batch-file, directory

I am putting together a script for my media server. I need to run through all the
files in a directory and then ultimately create softlinks in another folder to act as a video playlist. I'm just starting out and I'm already having problems with my batch script

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set TV="G:\TV"

FOR /R %TV% %%G in (.) DO (
 Pushd %%G
 Echo now in %%G

 for /f %%f IN ("dir /b") do (
    Echo %%f
 )

 Popd )
Echo "back home"
)
```

This produces a listing for each file but the filenames cut out after any spaces! It looks something like this:

```
now in G:\TV\UCB\UCB Season 3\.
Upright
Upright
Upright
Upright
...
now in G:\TV\Venture Bros\Season 3\.
File Not Found
now in G:\TV\Venture Bros\Season 4\.
The.Venture.Bros.S04E03.HDTV.XviD-2HD.avi
The.Venture.Bros.S04E04.HDTV.XviD-2HD.avi
The.Venture.Bros.S04E05.HDTV.XviD-2HD.avi
```

What can I do to fix this? Once I have the file it should be easy to create a soft link.

Comment: I think this (batch programming) belongs on superuser.

Comment: You should modify your FOR/F-loop to `FOR /F "delims="` as the standard delims are `space` and `tab`

Comment: do I just add the "delims="? Anything inside of it?

Comment: This `for /f "delims=" %%f IN ("dir /b") do (...` disables the delims, so you got the full filename in `%%f`, else it will split at the first space

Answer (score 0):

Just add quotes around your file names:

```
Pushd "%%G"
```

Comment: Any other places where that's needed?

Comment: No luck, getting the same results just with quotes around them

Answer (score 0):

you may replace all your BAT with a simple oneliner `FOR` loop.

```
FOR /R G:\TV %%f in (*) do echo create soft link for %%f
```